# Firefox Quantum: Use Ctrl+J to open download manager

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Ctrl+J no longer opens up the download manager in firefox quantum. Now it is Ctrl+Shift+Y. Can I revert it?

Answer (score 0):

> You *can’t* revert it :/
>   Install a old version of Firefox for have the download manager with ctrl+j ;)

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotkey works good for things like this.

```
#Persistent

#IfWinActive ahk_exe firefox.exe
^j::SendInput ^+y     ; send new keystroke using Ctrl+J
#IfWinActive
```